# Replacement for old Radeon HD 4870 1-Gb 256 bit GDDR5

Tags: graphics-cards

I'm looking for a similar AMD cheap modern replacement of this card (Radeon HD 4870 1-Gb 256 bit GDDR5) for my old computer but i'm not very sure about the way to go. Price between (50$-100$)

What modern AMD card would have a similar or better performance and work with my computer in that price range?

The PC specs are:

- Intel Quad Q9550 2.83 Ghz
- RAM: 4 Gb 1333 MHz
- Motherboard: ASRock G41C-GS
- PSU: 750 W

Comment: What do you do on your computer? Which country (for shipping)? Why do you want to upgrade? (any specific performance bottlenecks?)

Comment: I don't want to upgrade the computer. I want similar performance. It's just that the GPU is starting to fall apart. In fact i have it to be able to test my software in that generation of computers to see how it behaves compared to newer computers.

Comment: What does your software do? Is it graphics intensive? If not, a graphics card isn't going to help the software perform.

Comment: I don't want it to perform better, i just want that computer to work in a similar way as i've said already. My sofware in fact is a grid computing cross CPU/GPU organic platform and that computer is just another node. I don't care about the specs as far as they are similar because it will just serve as a compatibility and processing reference.

Comment: So you're using the GPU as a benchmark/reference sample? It's quite difficult to match performance across architectures.

Comment: I'm not using it as a benchmark itself. That will be given by the final CPU/GPU processing power with the softwate in that given configuration. I just want that node to be quite similar, neither too much more powerful nor too less powerful. As simple as that. Just a quite similar GPU. And if the difference is somehow noticeable it doesn't matter much either, its just another node to do tests.

Comment: You don't want to upgrade a system, but you want new hardware.  This really makes no sense.

Comment: Have you considered buying a replacement  Radeon HD 4870 1-Gb 256 bit GDDR5? That way, you already have the drivers and know how it will function for your purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to purchase new, and want roughly comparable single-precision computing power, I recommend the [MSI Radeon R7 250](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127763&ignorebbr=1), $75 from Newegg.  It's got about 70% the single-precision speed of the 4870, twice the RAM, and draws half the power.  Note that if you need *double*-precision computing power, this is a bad choice: it's only 20% as powerful as your current card.

If you need double-precision computing power, I recommend you look on Amazon or Ebay for another 4870.  The HD 4000 series had unusually high double-precision performance, and a modern replacement will run you at least $200.

Comment: Well Mark you just hit the bulls-eye and gave an pretty good idea of price margins. Before reading your answer i already bought exactly the same card barely used. My software mainly uses nodes to perform OpenCL double precision calculations on miscelaneous configurations so testing the performance on some newer computers with newer cards the price went over 200$ to get better results. On top of that this card has been running day and night nonstop for years on a high demand basis with no problems. Given i won't upgrade the computer itself the same card was the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

### HD Radeon RX 460 is the way better option.

Since an AMD solution was explicitly requested for technical reasons, how about the [XFX HD Radeon RX 460 for $99](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150780)? It's significantly better than the R7 250 and not much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try a Nvidia GeForce 1050. It's about [$110 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M4MIU94) and good enough for your needs with that machine. Yes, it's Nvidia, but you don't need to replace an AMD with an AMD.

Anything more powerful than this, you should just consider upgrading your whole computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ryan. I know in general there's no point in sticking to one or another chipset, but for my specific software i've checked over a long time that midrange AMD cards are way more cost-effective than Nvidia options. Maybe that would be different if i used CUDA, but i can't.

Comment: Oh, darn. Yeah there's always the chip specific parallel computing solutions that are incompatible with the other vendor.

Comment: Now a GeForce 1050 is $160 LOL. IT'S A FOUR YEAR OLD CARD.